# Displaying numbers on QLCDNumber widget

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I am bit new to Qt and python. I have created a simple GUI which consist of vertical slider and a `QLCDNumber` widget. I have somehow accessed the value of the slider by using a function. But now I want to show the newly generated value in the `QLCDNumber` display. How can I do it? Is there any way to display the new value (`ipp`) in the `QLCDNumber` display? My code is as follows:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(733, 498)
        self.centralWidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralWidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralWidget"))
        self.verticalSlider = QtGui.QSlider(self.centralWidget)
        self.verticalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 80, 20, 331))
        self.verticalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Vertical)
        self.verticalSlider.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalSlider"))
        self.lcdNumber = QtGui.QLCDNumber(self.centralWidget)
        self.lcdNumber.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(320, 180, 191, 81))
        self.lcdNumber.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("lcdNumber"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.menuBar = QtGui.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menuBar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 733, 21))
        self.menuBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("menuBar"))
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.mainToolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.mainToolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("mainToolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.mainToolBar)
        self.statusBar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusBar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.verticalSlider, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("valueChanged(int)")), self.abc)


    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))

    def abc(self, ip):
        self.ipp = ip - 10

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 10):

You need add a simple function

```
def abc(self, ip):
        self.ipp = ip - 10
        self.lcdNumber.display(self.ipp)
```

this will display your newly generated value